# How to create a firebase sign in?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard
      let emailsignin = emailSignIn?.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
      let passwordsignin = passwordSignIn?.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    else {
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailsignin, password: passwordsignin) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
          self.errorLabel3.text = "Invalid username or password"
          self.errorLabel3.alpha = 1
        } else {
          self.transitionToHome()
        } 
    }
}
```

Although nothing happens, if I type in the wrong info no error label is shown and if I type in the right Info I don't transition to the home screen which is what the function does. Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Comment: can you show the code inside `transitionToHome`?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: One issue is the guard statement in `loginTapped`. If either of the let statements fail, the `else { return` will occur and it will silently fail and you'll never know why. Also, there's no info about what troubleshooting you've done. Within the Auth.auth() method make the very first line `print("inside completion handler")` and then within the `if error !=nil` add a `print("THERE WAS AN ERROR!")` and then within the `else {` add `print("going to transition home")` then run the code and watch the console. *This is basic troubleshooting and will help you determine where your code is failing.*

Comment: @Jay the code is failing in the guard statement although how should I fix that?

Comment: The issue is how your handling optionals. see this `emailSignIn?` that ? means it's an optional and *could* be nil (which it probably is in this case) so then forcing your code to try to access properties of a nil var will fail `emailSignIn?.text!`. We don't know what `emailSignIn` or `passwordSignIn` is but generally speaking you want to verify those are not nil before using them `guard let thing = emailSignIn else { print("emailSignIn was nil!); return }`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this information in their documentation, that I think will be very helpful to you. Check it out [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui?authuser=0).

For your error messages you may want to incorporate UIAlertController so that you can popup a warning to the user.

```
 if let e = error {
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: e.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
         self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Once you are able to authenticate successfully you will just need to perform your segue to the next VC.

Comment: The problem isn't with the error because when I enter the correct information nothing happens either and I know the transition to home function is right because I use it on sign up.